# TURNJS UNBIND CLICK EVENT

Tags: jquery, turnjs

I am using the JS library turnjs for a flip book and it works great. I added a logo and a link for visitors to be able to return to home page. The link back to the home page is hidden on load and set to display with a delay of 7 seconds but when you click on the link nothing happens.

I looked around for suggestions and found a few but still have not been able to to get the link to work.  Here is the code I am using for the link:

CSS:

```
.inicio {
border: 3px solid white;
color: white;
left: 10px;
padding: 10px;
position: absolute;
top: 150px;
}
a {
color: white;
}
```

HTML:

```
<header>
<img src="losgens.png" class="logo" alt="Los Generales Revolucionarios">
<h3 class="inicio"><a href="http://www.losgeneralesrevolucionarios.com/" class="click">INICIO</a></h3>
</header>
```

JQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("h3.inicio").hide()

        setTimeout(function() {
            $("h3.inicio").fadeIn(1500);
        },7000);

    $('a.click').unbind('click');
});
</script>
```

I found the $('a.click').unbind('click'); as a suggestion (amongs others) but it does not enable the click function. Any ideas??

Comment: Why should `$('a.click').unbind('click')` "enable the click function" (whatever you mean by that)? `$('a.click').unbind('click')` looks up all links with the `click` class, and removes all click handlers that were attached to it from jQuery.

Comment: Because I saw this as a suggestion from another post. As I understood, the turnjs code disables the click event and this "unbind" method releases the selected element from this. But my click event on my link still does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept looking around for an answer and trying different things and I realized upon inspection with firebug that I could not select with the mouse the targeted area (the link) and that perhaps it had something to do with it's z-index. By increasing its z-index I noticed I could now select it and the link now works. So the solution was to modify the css like this:

```
.inicio {
border: 3px solid white;
color: white;
left: 10px;
padding: 10px;
position: absolute;
top: 150px;
z-index: 1000; /* the handling! */
}
```

Here is the link:

http://www.losgeneralesrevolucionarios.com/menu/